# Is it possible to remove small polygons from Census Block shapefile?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I just pulled up a shapefile that plots census blocks (TIGER product) using Quantum and I noticed that there are well over 1000 small polygons that aren't census blocks that are (I assume) used to buffer between census block polygons and small slivers of open area.  Is there any way I can remove these irrelevant polygons so that I am left with a clean "grid" of census blocks that are all adjoining without these small polygons?

Comment: Do the small areas have valid data attributes? Something as simple as filtering out any that don't have a value for population may get you what you are after.

Comment: The little slivers have NULL values. Is it possible to filter these out and clean the geometries?

Answer (score 2):

If all the slivers have null values for a particular field, select them using:

```
"field name" is null
```

and then delete.